# Is it possible to get the price of bitcoin in USD from the coinbase API for a specific time in the past?

Tags: coinbase-api

GET https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/:currency_pair/spot

This price seems to be the current price

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Coinbase API v2 Getting Historic Price for Multiple Days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51417285/coinbase-api-v2-getting-historic-price-for-multiple-days)

Answer (score 0):

This question already has answers. Copy and pasted from here: [Coinbase API v2 Getting Historic Price for Multiple Days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51417285/coinbase-api-v2-getting-historic-price-for-multiple-days)

> Any reason you aren't using coinbase pro?

> The new api is very easy to use. Simply add the get command you want followed by the parameters separated with a question mark. Here is the new historic rates api documentation: https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#get-historic-rates

> The get command with the new api most similar to prices is "candles". It requires three parameters to be identified, start and stop time in iso format and granularity which is in seconds. Here is an example:

> https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/BTC-USD/candles?start=2018-07-10T12:00:00&stop=2018-07-15T12:00:00&granularity=900

> EDIT: also, note the time zone is not for your time zone, I believe its GMT.